# How to add a number at end of username

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

I need to generate usernames that start with a letter of the alphabet, followed by the date and that ends with numbers from 1 to 20. For a total of 520 names.
Here's the variables I came up with:

```
$letter = 97..122 | foreach {[char]$_}  
$date = get-date -UFormat %a%y%d  
$name = $letter | ForEach-Object { $_ + $date }
```

So I managed to put my letters and my dates together, to form names like **aWed1513**, which is exactly what I need, but when it comes to make each to end with numbers, I'm stuck. Tried with a For loop by adding incrementing $i to $name, but doesn't work..

Comment: What is your expected output look like just aWed15131....aWed151320 for each letter?

Comment: Exactly yes, sorry for putting the tag in question btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're just about there.  Your `for` loop should look like this:

```
$names = @()
$letter = 97..122 | foreach {[char]$_}  
$date = get-date -UFormat %a%y%d  

for($i = 1; $i -le 20; $i++) {
    $names += $letter | ForEach-Object { '{0}{1}{2}' -f $_, $date, $i }    
}
$names
```

Comment: That does the trick, thank you very much, my mind was getting foggy over this.

Comment: You should take the `$letter` declaration out of the loop. You don't need to keep re-initializing it. Same with date... so that it does not change during processing.

Comment: Using the format operator (`-f`) might be a little more PoSh: `'{0}{1}{2}' -f $_, $date, $i`. Also, I'd recommend moving the calculation of character list and date outside the `for` loop, because they're not supposed to change inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast feedback, new here but always loved the site. Hopefully I'll be able to help also after my formation. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to the answer given that just adds another ForEach-Object to the OP's original code:

```
$letter = 97..122 | foreach {[char]$_}  
$date = get-date -UFormat %a%y%d  
$names = $letter | ForEach-Object { $_ + $date } | ForEach-Object { for($i=1;$i -le 20;$i++) { $_ + $i } }
```

And to shorten to get same result:

```
$letter = 97..122 | foreach {[char]$_}  
$date = get-date -UFormat %a%y%d  
$names = $letter | ForEach-Object { for($i=1;$i -le 20;$i++) { $_ + $date + $i } }
```

Comment: Nice, I was wondering if $_ would refer to $letter or result of last redirection, or if it would get amibiguous... good tip thank you